# window.print very slow . Alert comes before print

Tags: javascript

In the below code second alert comes before the first print pop page.
Search results says window.print is a OS functionality and it does not have return value.

Second alert should come only after the print popup.
Kindly help

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        for(i=0;i<6;i++){
            alert('Printing Copy:'+i);
            window.print();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: you call it before, and it comes before... What's wrong?

Comment: Also, know that in your case `alert()` will pop only once. Same for `print()`

Comment: what browser you are use? I have not this issue with chrome, both function calls are blocking...

Comment: I ran this snippet in my chrome console and every alert is displayed before the corresponding print popup (i.e. `alert0` then print model then `alert1` then print model... etc). what browser are you using?

Comment: "second alert comes before the first print pop page". What does the _second alert_ say?

Comment: Are your users really that inept to change to number of prints to 6 in the dialog?

Answer (score 0):

`window.print` is an asynchronous function. "Asynchronous" means that the execution will immediately return to the calling function, and whatever that is expected to be done by the function will happen in another time.

What happens in your case is this: You are looping several times, and each time you are `alert`ing the user that you are going to print the document, and then you call `print`. However, the `print` call will immediately return, and your loop will get to the second iteration before it pops up the print dialog for the first iteration.

As a remedy, you can use `onbeforeprint` to alert the user that you are going to print the document.

```
function myFunction() {
    for(i=0; i<6; i++){
        window.onbeforeprint = function(){
            alert("Printing copy:" + i);
        }

        window.print();
    }
}
```

Note: If you do not understand how this code works, you may want to search and learn a bit about "JavaScript closures", "callbacks", and "asynchronous functions".